# how to disable facebook login dialog

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm new in facebook SDK and iOS deverlop, my app have a problem when user login facebook, when I use a same account fb to login, my app always show this login dialog:
[image]

I want my app only show that dialog when a fb account login in the first time, but I don't know how to do it, here is my code:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error {
switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        if (!error) {
            mainViewController *mainView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainView animated:YES];
            // We have a valid session
            NSLog(@"User session found");
        }
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
 object:session];

if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

}

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"email",
                        @"user_likes",
                        nil];

return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)authLogin:(id)sender {
[self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
```

}

I use fb sdk 3.2 and ios simulator 6.1

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you,have a look :

[Facebook developer section](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/)